# WSO2 AM - How to create API with only HTTP query parameters?

Tags: api, http, wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to create API in WSO2 AM for existing endpoint which is communicating only through HTTP with query parameters?

Like http://server:port/service?parameter1=x&parameter2=y

Is there any way how to put Gateway between client and such HTTP query server to handle API?

I was able to find how to create REST, SOAP, WS API, but I do not know how to proceed with HTTP only with query parameters.

Comment: I think the section 5 of this post shows how to add parameters. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Create+and+Publish+an+API   Just click on the API resource and the section to add parameters will apear.

Comment: I added to API Definition query parameters `parameter1` and `parameter2`. But still, when I am trying to invoke API through API Console, I am getting `"error": "no response from server"`.